# Write one record to multiple Access databases

Tags: ms-access

I have created a template form in Access for multiple users to record data.  The data they enter will be written to their own personal database, but I need the data to also write to a master database that compiles all users' records.  All the databases (the users personal databases and the master database) have identical fields (and each personal database, and the master database, has the same field identified with the primary key). At first, I thought linking the databases might work, but then I'll end up with 100+ linked tables in the master database and still no way to compile all records into one master table.  Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: ms-access is really limited in terms of multi-user experience. you are running up against this. hopefully someone will have a good idea for how to proceed.

Comment: How do you prevent each user's database from duplicating a primary key when it is past to the master database? Do you require the key be created in the master database table firest and then use that value for the user's database?

Comment: The users' PK field is "RecordID". In the master tbl, I created a new field called "MstrRecordID" (which is the master tbl PK) and I defined "RecordID" as a text field (which will allow duplicates if/when I can get the users' records to append).

Answer (score 1):

on the form in the user's access database there must be a control to enter in new data. inside this control, add an INSERT INTO statement to the table in the master database. for example:

'enter into user table
strSQL = "INSERT INTO userTable (field1, field2) VALUES (data1, data2)"
dbUser.Execute strSQL
'
'here you will open a connection to the master database
'
strSQL = "INSERT INTO userTable (field1, field2) VALUES (data1, data2)"
dbMaster.Execute strSQL

Comment: you dont need to necessarily link every user table to the master database but instead link the master table to every user databases. then you can simply insert into the table instead of opening a db connection every time.

Comment: The control to enter the new data is a button I created on the form named "SaveRecord"...when the user hits the button, the record is added to their local db table and then automatically closes the application for them.  So, here's the code I entered, given your suggestion yesterday (thank you, btw!!).  I'm not getting errors, however, the record is still not appending the master database table...perhaps I have the syntax in the wrong order?

Comment: Sub SaveRecord_Click()
On Error GoTo SaveRecord_Click_Err
    On Error Resume Next
    'When user clicks the "Submit & Close" button, the record appends local db table
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDataEntry
     'After record appends to local db table, same record appends Master db table
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO MasterTbl (*) VALUES (*)"
    [D:\MasterDatabase].Execute strSQL
   'After record appends to Master db table, the application closes
    DoCmd.Quit acSave
  If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If
SaveRecord_Click_Exit:

Comment: if youre not concerned with the users gaining access to the master table then i suggest you link to the master db table. to do this you go to 'external data' tab and under 'import' select access. navigate to the master db and to the master table. where you have the insert into mastertbl code, make sure mastertbl is the name of the master table in the user db not the name of the master table in the master db. ****just so you know, in order for the users to append the data to the master table (regardless of your append method), the user tables will need network access to the master database.****